# Одно или два «н» в отыменных прилагательных?

Tags: орфография

Когда мы говорим о кратких причастиях, мы знаем, что кол-во *н* бывает разное.

`Он воспитанна, но иногда неуравновешенна.`

`Эти ответы взаимосвязаны.`

Но когда мы говорит о кол-ве *н* в кратких прилагательных, от существительных образованных, оно всегда одно и то же, если в полной форме две *н*,  – два. Так?

`Поле было пустынно/пустыно.`

`Мои друзья все как один безымянны/безымяны.`

`Земля, по которой я ходил, была каменна/камена.`

`Чаёвка, мною выпитая, была травяна, а чаёвница, при этом использованная, – серебряна.` (Здесь по-любому одна – *травяной* и *серебряный* пишутся с одной.)

Comment: _По-любому_ через дефис.

Comment: Спасибо вам, сэр.

Comment: Я минусую до исправления, так как чаёвник - это остановка на перекус на Камчатке или топоним. То есть время или место, а вовсе не что-то, что можно выпить. А чаёвница - это любительница попить чай. Слова использованы абсолютно некорректно. Нельзя брать слова и составлять из них винегрет при этом спрашивая о какой-то грамотности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

**Поле было **пустынно**.*  Мои друзья **безымянны.***

Отыменные прилагательные обычно являются **относительными**,  лишь некоторые из них переходят в качественные.

Краткую форму могут иметь только **качественные** прилагательные.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (о краткой форме прилагательного **"каменный"**)

Краткая форма может использоваться при особой **стилизации текста,** например:

*А земля, по которой я ходил, была **каменна**, а поле-то вокруг пустынно.*

**[Вопрос № 286213.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB)**

Могут ведь **склоняться краткие прилагательные?** Интуиция подсказывает, что не всегда это возможно.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Краткие прилагательные изменялись по падежам в **древнерусском** языке. Следы этого древнего склонения мы находим **в сказках, былинах, пословицах:** на добра коня садился; Сказка ― ложь, да в ней намек: ***добру молодцу урок.***

В современном русском языке краткие формы прилагательных не склоняются. Это языковое изменение было связано с тем, что изначально в древнерусском языке **не было полных** форм прилагательных, были только краткие. Появившиеся полные формы в литературном языке **вытеснили** краткие формы в позиции **определения.** Сейчас мы не скажем по чисту полю, богата человека – скажем по чистому полю, богатого человека.

Краткие формы стали использоваться в составе **сказуемого** (например: Дом чист; Горница чиста; Человек богат) и – реже – как определения при подлежащем (Богат, хорош собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених), и поэтому все формы, кроме именительного падежа, перестали употребляться.

**[Литневская](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i3)**

Comment: По-любому неправильно *камена*, так как надо *каменна*.

Comment: Sir, you didn't like my answer, and that's understandable. So I supplemented it.

Comment: That's far better.

Answer (score 2):

Да, вы верно думаете. Если в полной форме две, то и в краткой будет две. Обратно: если в полной одна, то и в краткой одна. Так же и написание Н и НН в наречиях зависит от прилагательных.

***Поле было пустынно.*** *Пустынно* — краткое прилагательное, пишется с двумя Н, т. к. в полной форме две Н. А в полной форме две Н, потому что — вы это, возможно, знаете, но на всякий случай напишу и это — в корне -ПУСТЫН- 1 Н и в суффиксе вторая Н. Поэтому с двумя.

***Мои друзья все как один безымянны.*** С двумя Н, потому что в полной форме две Н. А в полной форме две Н, т. к. это прилагательное образовано от существительного на -МЯ (*имя*).

А слов **каменна**, **серебряна**, **травяна** не существует, т. к. они образованы от **относительных** прилагательных, а от относительных **нельзя** образовать краткую форму.

Поэтому лучше написать в полной:

***Земля, по которой я ходил, была каменной***;

***Чаёвка, мною выпитая, была травяной, а чаёвница, при этом использованная, – серебряной***.